# Cufflinks Bubble Chart for more than one series

Tags: python, plotly

How to plot a  Bubble chart with more than one series using cufflinks in python?
Like this one: https://plot.ly/~jorgesantos/396/cufflinks-bubble-chart.embed

I got how to plot a bubble chart with one series as here: https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/cufflinks/#bubble-charts

Example Data:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~jenny/notOcto/STAT545A/examples/gapminder/data/gapminderDataFiveYear.txt', sep='\t')
```

How can I keep every continent in a given color for a bubble chart that can be plotted like this:

```
df2007.iplot(kind='bubble', x='gdpPercap', y='lifeExp', size='pop', text='country',
             xTitle='GDP per Capita', yTitle='Life Expectancy',
             filename='cufflinks')

    country      year   pop          continent  lifeExp gdpPercap
1   Afghanistan  2007   3.188992e+07    Asia    43.828  974.580338
2   Albania      2007   3.600523e+06    Europe  76.423  5937.029526
3   Algeria      2007   3.333322e+07    Africa  72.301  6223.367465
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So If I understand correctly you just want to color the bubbles by continent. Then map the colors using the option `categories` and change colors using `colors`:

```
df2007.iplot(kind='bubble', x='gdpPercap', y='lifeExp', size='pop', text='country',
             categories = 'continent', colors=['rgb(215,25,28)','rgb(253,174,97)','rgb(255,255,191)','rgb(171,217,233)','rgb(44,123,182)'],
             xTitle='GDP per Capita', yTitle='Life Expectancy',
             filename='simple-bubble-chart')
```

[image]